# d3- Find max key/value in nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have an array of 3 nested arrays, each containing 3 objects. What d3 syntax do I use to find the max value of data1 in all of the data?

Is it something like,

```
function find_max(all_data, i){
    return d3.max(all_data[i].data1)
}
```

Here's my data structure:

```
all_data = [
        [{data1:2, age:6},
         {data1:4, age:5},
         {data1:5, age:4}],

        [{data1:7, age:2},
         {data1:1, age:9},
         {data1:0, age:8}],

        [{data1:5, age:9},
         {data1:6, age:9},
         {data1:8, age:6}]
       ]
```

Basically, I want it to return 8. Thanks for the help!! I can't quite get it right.

Comment: How are you calling that function?

Comment: var max = function find_max(all_data)
(I added a function name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a mix of [`d3.max`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#max) and [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) operations:

```
d3.max(all_data.map(d => d3.max(d.map(n => n.data1)))) // 8
```

This finds the max of each nested array using `d3.max` to find the max and a `map` operation to transform nested arrays of objects into an array of `data1` values (`[2, 4, 5]` for the first nested array).

```
[{data1:2, age:6}, {data1:4, age:5}, {data1:5, age:4}].map(n => n.data1) // [2, 4, 5]
d3.max([{data1:2, age:6}, {data1:4, age:5}, {data1:5, age:4}].map(n => n.data1)) // 5
```

And with each sub-max, we find the global max using `d3.max` again.

```js
var all_data = [
  [{data1:2, age:6},
    {data1:4, age:5},
    {data1:5, age:4}],

  [{data1:7, age:2},
    {data1:1, age:9},
    {data1:0, age:8}],

  [{data1:5, age:9},
    {data1:6, age:9},
    {data1:8, age:6}]
];

console.log(d3.max(all_data.map(d => d3.max(d.map(n => n.data1)))));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

---

If you are comfortable with the notion of [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), you could also do as follow:

```
d3.max(all_data.flatMap(d => d.map(n => n.data1))); // 8
```

but this requires creating a `flatMap` function for arrays:

```
Array.prototype.flatMap = function(lambda) {
  return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], this.map(lambda));
};
```

where the `flatMap` operation flattens the nested lists:

```
all_data.flatMap(d => d.map(n => n.data1)) // [2, 4, 5, 7, 1, 0, 5, 6, 8]
```

---

Finally, if you'd like to get both the max and the min at once, we can use a mix of `Array.flatMap` and [`d3.extent`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#extent):

```
var [min, max] = d3.extent(all_data.flatMap(d => d.map(n => n.data1)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way is to nest `d3.max()`:

```
function findMax(data) {
  return d3.max(data, arr =>    // return max of all nested max values
    d3.max(arr, d => d.data1)   // return max of each nested array
  );
}
```

The outer call to `d3.max()` uses its accessor function to get access to the maximum value of each nested array. The inner call will determine the maximum value for each nested array. For this purpose it defines an accessor function to return the `data1` property.

Have a look at the following working demo:

```js
const all_data = [
        [{data1:2, age:6},
         {data1:4, age:5},
         {data1:5, age:4}],

        [{data1:7, age:2},
         {data1:1, age:9},
         {data1:0, age:8}],

        [{data1:5, age:9},
         {data1:6, age:9},
         {data1:8, age:6}]
       ];
       
function findMax(data) {
  return d3.max(data, arr =>
    d3.max(arr, d => d.data1)
  );
}

console.log(findMax(all_data));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
```

---

Alternatively, you could first use [`d3.merge()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#merge) to merge your nested arrays into one and apply `d3.max()` to that merged array.

```
function findMax(data) {
  return d3.max(d3.merge(data), d => d.data1);
}
```

Here is the working demo:

```js
const all_data = [
        [{data1:2, age:6},
         {data1:4, age:5},
         {data1:5, age:4}],

        [{data1:7, age:2},
         {data1:1, age:9},
         {data1:0, age:8}],

        [{data1:5, age:9},
         {data1:6, age:9},
         {data1:8, age:6}]
       ];
       
function findMax(data) {
  return d3.max(d3.merge(all_data), d => d.data1);
}

console.log(findMax(all_data));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map the inner `data1` values and get the max value and then take the result for the outer array.

```js
var all_data = [[{ data1: 2, age: 6 }, { data1: 4, age: 5 }, { data1: 5, age: 4 } ], [{ data1: 7, age: 2 }, { data1: 1, age: 9 }, { data1: 0, age: 8 }], [{ data1: 5, age: 9 }, { data1: 6, age: 9 }, { data1: 8, age: 6 }]],
    maxData1 = Math.max(...all_data.map(a => Math.max(...a.map(({ data1 }) => data1))));
    
console.log(maxData1);
```